# JAVA Program not running in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

```
public class heater {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Orignal temperature");
        heater1 var1= new heater1();
                var1.show();
        System.out.println("Cooler temperature");
        heater1 var2= new heater1 ();
        var2.cold();
        var2.show();
        System.out.println("Warmer temperature");
        heater1 var3 = new heater1();
        var3.hot();
        var3.show();
    }

}
class heater1 {
    double temperature;
    double warmer;
    double cooler;

    heater1 (){
        temperature= 40;
        warmer=0;
        cooler=0;
    }
    void cold(){
        cooler=temperature - 5;
        temperature=cooler;
    }
    void hot(){
        warmer = temperature + 5;
        temperature = warmer;
    }
    void show(){
        System.out.println(temperature);
    }

}
```

Hi,

I am facing a problem regarding a java project in intellij IDEA. I had created a project in intelliJ IDEA n it was working perfectly fine(as you can see in the above code).Now when i open the project again it is not running.

The running option is black. Whenever I click on it a pop up window opens which says "Edit configurations.." I don't know what to do?

Comment: Is your Java classpath configured for the project?

Comment: Runs fine for me in IntelliJ 2017.3.  You're doing something quite wrong.

Comment: the run option is black i donno even though the build is working properly

Comment: @Vineeth i donno but i have added everything in the software, so probably.

Comment: I created a new Java class called heater in a folder marked as a Java source folder - you can tell because it's colored blue.  Once that was done I right-clicked on it and asked IntelliJ to run the main method.

Comment: now iv tried opening the project directly from where it was set(folder). It asked me whether i wanna open it in intelliJ IDEA. Now its working fine.

Comment: Poor title. Edit to summarize the specific technical issue in your question.